# Fade in JSON ajax list with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following slider:

https://jsfiddle.net/lucasmosele/px9ar93y/1/

My interval code is as follows:

```
var counter = 1;
var elements = json.slider.length;

// Set timer between quotes being visible
$("#quotes li:first-child").addClass("active");
int = setInterval(function(){
        $("#quotes li:nth-child(" + counter + ")").removeClass("active");
        $("#quotes li:nth-child(" + counter + ")").next().addClass("active");
    if (counter === elements){
        counter = 1;
    } else {
        counter++;
    }
}, 3000);
```

I want to be able to have the new content fadeIn, I have tried .fadeIn:

```
$("#quotes li:nth-child(" + counter + ")").next().addClass("active").fadeIn("slow");
```

but I got behavior that I didn't necessarily want. I also tried creating css transitions between li and li.active, but for some reason they dont show up unless .fadeIn is set to "slow".

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: FYI: You have a logic error. The first quote only displays once. And every time you get to the end of the list you have one frame of no quotes, though that might be desired.

Comment: @DanielCook Thanks Daniel, I didn't want to ask two questions at the same time. Is there any recommended fix for this? I'm relatively new to JQuery/Javascript so this has been a pretty failure-ridden process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
$("#quotes li:nth-child(" + counter + ")").next().hide().addClass("active").fadeIn("slow");
```

[Play it here](https://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/px9ar93y/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for:

```
$("#quotes li:first-child").addClass("active");
int = setInterval(function(){
        $("#quotes li:nth-child(" + counter + ")").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $("#quotes li:nth-child(" + counter + ")").next().fadeIn('slow');
        });
    if (counter === elements){
        counter = 1;
    } else {
        counter++;
    }
}, 3000);
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/px9ar93y/6/